Add a link to a table in rmarkdown document
I want to add a link to a word with a table within the same rmarkdown document. Here is what I tried, but this did not work.
---
title: 'test'
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
---

{r glob_opt, echo = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE )

**Dummy text**  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, see `[sample data](#tab:iris)` consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse neque risus, interdum ac nunc non, tempus sollicitudin sapien.  
 

After, see I would like to add a link to the table on the sample data.
{r packages}
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gt)


{r tab.cap= 'iris'}
head(iris, 3) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(title = "Table 1: sample data"))

